# Why i need to set the Android SDK path every time I close PhpStorm?

Tags: android, sdk, phpstorm, environment

Every time I restart PhpStorm and want to build my phonegap application to create the apk file, I need to set the `android-sdk` path with the terminal command: `set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\android\android-sdk`.

Is there a way to set it once for all?

Comment: what about setting this variable in Windows control panel (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? setting it in terminal only works for current terminal session

Comment: smart solution, thank you!